# What is the opposite of pulse width modulation called?

Tags: motor, pwm, motor-controller

If I want to control a motor by simply giving it a variable specific voltage or current, to control the RPM, not by flipping the power on and off as in pulse width modulation, what is that called?

Comment: .....DC?  ......

Comment: variable DC voltage?

Comment: Linear? Analog?

Comment: Lowpass filtered PWM?

Comment: The IRIG Inter Range Instrumentation Group standardized many forms of modulation, about 1950. PAM pulse-amplitude-modulation might be your answer. I worked for a company that handed the Ground Data recording and de-commutation (sorting out of the multiplexed data) and driving the myriad Chart Recorders, for the Gemini and Apollo projects. Learned a lot.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I'm amazed nobody answered this question correctly and decided to go off on unrelated tangents. The correct terminology you are looking for is called **Constant Voltage.**

Comment: A "variable specific voltage" is called a "constant voltage"? How do you "control the RPM" with that? A constant voltage results in a constant RPM.

Comment: Why did this get both an upvote and a check mark?! New contributor or not, this answer is not only condescending, but wrong. I'm sorry, but -1 from me.

Answer (score 9):

Controlling a DC motor by simply controlling the voltage is called armature voltage control or adjustable voltage control. That is not really the opposite of pulse width modulation. It is a different way of doing the same thing. You might say it is an analog method rather than a digital method.

Controlling the current is a method of controlling torque. That can be used for speed control by adjusting the current in response to a speed error signal.

Controlling a DC motor using a controlled rectifier (thyristor) is sometimes called pulse amplitude control. More often, it is called SCR (silicon controlled rectifier) control.

For AC motors, voltage control is quite limited. Frequency control is preferred.

Comment: How did you know that the question was related to motor and motor-controller?

Comment: PWM isn't really digital in itself, really, since it isn't *necessarily* discrete-time. You can have analog PWM, and that is actually what some simple (and old-fashioned) DC-DC converters use (hysteresis control with a few op amps).

Comment: @Harry Svensson Are you serious? The body of the question seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Hearth I agree. It isn't digital in itself, but in a liberal use of the term, you might say that.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Oh, it appears that I was very blind, I missed the word "motor" that OP wrote. Whoopsie.

Comment: He's asking for what do you call voltage that you plug into a thing where you don't need PWM. The answer is Constant Voltage